# Algorithm to traverse grid of connected paths

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to figure out an algorithm that will allow me to traverse a grid of connected paths that I have created so that I can determine if there are any paths that are not connected. For example, see the image below of my grid:

[image]

Everything works fine, the only problem is the block near the bottom left corner that is not connected to anything. I want all the paths to be connected to each other in some way.

So I need to write an algorithm that works through the grid and determines if there are blocks that are not connected.

Currently, the grid is build using a two-dimensional array, as follows:

```
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        hz[x] = new Array(10);

        for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            hz[x][y] = new block(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Each element in the array contains an object of type `block`, as follows:

```
function block(top, bottom, left, right){
    this.top = top;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
```

To determine the paths, I have a bunch of code that randomly assigns edges to each element by making the `left`, `top`, `bottom` and/or `right` values true or false. There are additional conditions for blocks on the edge. Each block is then assigned an image based on which of its values are true and false.

Please can you help me to figure out some sort of algorithm that lets me traverse this structure to check if each block is connected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms

Comment: Is the asymmetry in the upper right (one away from the top; rightmost and next rightmost) intended?

Comment: If you want your properties that signify the edges to be either `true` or `false`, why do you initialise them with `0`?

Comment: No, I just realised that dead ends like that won't actually work. I need to fix that

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm to do that is finding the connected components. As its name suggests, it finds groups of nodes that are connected together.

So, if you have several components, all of your blocks aren't connected together.

The idea is to iterate through the blocks. For each block finds all the blocks you can reach from your starting point: this makes one component. Now, with a correct implementation, you only have to visit each block once, so it's very efficient.

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) page about this problem is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically a graph and you're asking if the graph is connected or not. [graph algorithm finding if graph is connected, bipartite, has cycle and is a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394254/graph-algorithm-finding-if-graph-is-connected-bipartite-has-cycle-and-is-a-tre)

Comment: yes, the question there conftlicts with itself at that point, so I've just edited my answer with another page.